# Fixed effect panel model slopes

Tags: r, time-series, econometrics, panel-data

I am running a fixed effects panel model on monthly financial data. My dependent variable is $X_{t}-X_{t-1}$ and my explanatory variables are the lags $X_{t-1} - X_{t-2}$, $X_{t-2} - X_{t-3}$ and so on. Using plm in R, I fitted a model with 1-6 lags. I was wondering why as the number of lags/explanatory variables increased, the coefficients for those variables increased in magnitude. I have around 20 financial indicators that I am fitting a model to, and I've found that this pattern of increasing coefficients is consistent with every indicator I try.

Here are my results for one indicator:

```
Call: plm(formula = Indicator ~ Lag1 + Lag2 + Lag3 + Lag4 + Lag5 + 
Lag6, data = d.subset, model = "within", index = c("CU", 
"Date"))

Balanced Panel: n=42, T=24, N=1008

Coefficients :
     Estimate Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)   
Lag1 -0.067498   0.031912 -2.1152 0.034673 * 
Lag2 -0.058659   0.031855 -1.8414 0.065866 . 
Lag3 -0.103175   0.032083 -3.2158 0.001344 **
Lag4 -0.062016   0.031900 -1.9441 0.052174 . 
Lag5 -0.032046   0.032146 -0.9969 0.319068   
Lag6 -0.047227   0.032029 -1.4745 0.140665   

Call:
plm(formula = Indicator ~ Lag1 + Lag2 + Lag3 + Lag4 + Lag5, data =        d.subset, 
model = "within", index = c("CU", "Date"))

Coefficients :
      Estimate Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)   
Lag1 -0.066416   0.031923 -2.0805 0.037742 * 
Lag2 -0.056417   0.031838 -1.7720 0.076711 . 
Lag3 -0.099295   0.031995 -3.1035 0.001969 **
Lag4 -0.058248   0.031816 -1.8307 0.067448 . 
Lag5 -0.029565   0.032122 -0.9204 0.357602  

Call:
plm(formula = Indicator ~ Lag1 + Lag2 + Lag3 + Lag4, data = d.subset, 
    model = "within", index = c("CU", "Date"))

Coefficients :
      Estimate Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)   
Lag1 -0.064960   0.031881 -2.0376 0.041865 * 
Lag2 -0.053906   0.031718 -1.6995 0.089546 . 
Lag3 -0.097377   0.031924 -3.0502 0.002349 **
Lag4 -0.056872   0.031779 -1.7896 0.073828 .  

Call:
plm(formula = Indicator ~ Lag1 + Lag2 + Lag3, data = d.subset, 
model = "within", index = c("CU", "Date"))

Coefficients :
  Estimate Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)   
Lag1 -0.059869   0.031790 -1.8833 0.059964 . 
Lag2 -0.050806   0.031707 -1.6023 0.109410   
Lag3 -0.094498   0.031920 -2.9604 0.003147 **


Call:
plm(formula = Indicator ~ Lag1 + Lag2, data = d.subset, model = "within", 
index = c("CU", "Date"))

Coefficients :
      Estimate Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)  
Lag1 -0.055762   0.031887 -1.7487  0.08066 .
Lag2 -0.046421   0.031800 -1.4598  0.14467  

Call:
plm(formula = Indicator ~ Lag1, data = d.subset, model = "within", 
 index = c("CU", "Date"))

Coefficients :
      Estimate Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)  
Lag1 -0.053395   0.031865 -1.6757  0.09412 .
```